# How to display a number from an API on my website?

Tags: javascript, html

```
    You are visitor # <span id=VisitorCounter></span>
    <script>

fetch("https://6ka4boms3b.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Visits/visitornumber", {
  method: "GET", 
 // mode: "cors",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    //"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
    //"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
  },
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {console.log(data);})
.catch((error) => {console.log(error);})

    </script>
```

This is what I have so far, my website only displays "You are visitor#" and I am not sure how to display the number grabbed from my API.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to your Visitor Counter span by using `document.getElementById()` and then pass the API value to the `innerHTML` of that span.

```js
var visitorCounter = document.getElementById("VisitorCounter");
fetch("https://6ka4boms3b.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Visits/visitornumber", {
    method: "GET",
    // mode: "cors",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      //"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
      //"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
    },
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    visitorCounter.innerHTML = data;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

```html
You are visitor # <span id=VisitorCounter></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use  **.textContent** inside your code.

```js
let getVisitorCounts = document.getElementById("VisitorCounter");

fetch("https://6ka4boms3b.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Visits/visitornumber", {
    method: "GET",
    // mode: "cors",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      //"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
      //"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
    },
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    /* ADDED */
    getVisitorCounts.textContent = data;
    
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

```html
You are visitor # <span id="VisitorCounter"></span>
```